# What's the most efficient way to convert hardcoded strings to XML/resource files?

Tags: xml, string, resources, hardcoded

I have a very large program (thousands of lines of code) in which countless strings have been hardcoded into the UI. I understand this is considered bad practice, and I need to correct this massive error by putting everything into resource files. Short of creating hundreds of resources files myself and going through the code and manually editing each line to reference strings in the resource files, what's the most efficient way to go about this? Can I programmatically pull everything from the code and generate a bunch of resource files, or am I  looking at weeks of extra work?

Comment: I haven't used it, but ReSharper offers help with localization: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html

Comment: Even if I don't use Resharper for this purpose, thanks for showing it to me. The tools and added functionality look really helpful